# Scaling rectangle and keeping ratio when height and/or width exceed container

Tags: geometry, ratio, rectangles

I have a 2D box with a `Height` of 206 and a `Width` of 202.

Inside of this box is a `Rectangle`. It fits until the height and/or width exceed the height/width of its container.

How can I scale the `Rectangle` and get a new height and width so whenever it exceeds the container box it shrinks back to the largest possible size with the same ratio while fitting into the container?

Example: The `Rectangle` has a height of `200` and a width of `100`. I increase the height to `2000` and the width to `1000`. I want to shrink it back down to a size that will fit in the box with a height of `206` and width of `202` while keeping the ratio of `2000:1000`.

Note: The height might not always greater than the width.

Comment: You might want to look at Doug Dilon's answer here: https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-area-of-the-largest-rectangle-that-fits-in-a-cylinder-with-height-h-and-radius-r . You have an added constraint but the same principle is still useful

Comment: Let's say you have a box of dimension $(w_b, h_b)$ and a rectangle of dimension $(w_p, h_p)$, the scaling factor will be $$\min\left(\frac{w_b}{w_p},\frac{h_b}{h_p}, 1\right)$$ The $1$ here is to ensure when your box is large enough, don't scale the rectangle.